# what's the best way to map object to random format json string

Tags: c#, json, serialization, converters

I am currently integrating with a third party API, they are accepting json string similar to the following format :

```
{    
"test-specialism": null,
"salaryCollection": [
    {
      "id":
               {
                   "jobtypeid": 1
               },  
"maxsalary": 564,
        "minsalary": 123,
        "salarycurrency": "GBP",
        "salarytype": "A"
    },
{
        "id":
               {
                   "jobtypeid": 2
               },
               "maxsalary": null,
               "minsalary": null,
               "salarycurrency": "GBP",
               "salarytype": null
           },
    }],
```

}

And here is my object:

```
   public class Salary {
    public double Minimum { get; set; }
    public double Maximum { get; set; }
    public PaymentFrequency Frequency { get; set; }
    public double Step { get; set; }
    public int JobTypeId { get; set; }
    public SalarySetting() {        }

}

public class Alert {
   public string Specialism {get;set;}
   public Salary Permanent { get; set; }
   public Salary Temporary { get; set; }
   public Salary Contract { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the object structure is very inconsistent with the JSON strucuture. What would be an ideal way to convert the object to that specified json string？ I've tries JSONProperty to map the property, that doesn't seem to work well in this case.

Comment: You should create a classes structure that will have the same levels of nesting as the json structure, then just convert your existed structure to new one and then serialize the last one

Comment: So why don't you create an object with the right schema?

Comment: Why would we put the Id fields as an Object with only one jobtypeid field in it?  The json structure doesn't make sense to me, that's why I am trying to get away with create class just for mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). Example :

```
public class Product{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }   
}
```

And I will adding some instances to Lists :

```
Product p1 = new Product {Name="Product1",ID="1"};
Product p2 = new Product {Name="Product2",ID="2"};
List<Product> pList = new List<Product>() {p1,p2};
```

Then I'm going to serialize it :

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = serializer.Serialize(pList);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create classes that describe your json
2. Use [**AutoMapper**](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map from your classes to json-related classes.

Comment: that's what i am trying to get away with. The json object structure is very inconsistent in the API, I would need to create JSON related class for each calls and then class would only be used in mapping function.

Comment: You NEED to put this mapping somewhere. You could use serializer converters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx) but it may be less readable in my opinion. If you have to structures that requires mapping to each other you can't get away from implementing the mapping somewhere.